# HQL query joining three Hibernate entity classes

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-query

I have three Hibernate entity classes - Shipment, Parcel and User - mapping respectively tables `shipments`, `parcels` and `users` (see attached db scheme). Parcels represent the "connection point" between a User and a Shipment as each `parcel` has an `user_id` and a `shipment_id`.

What I need to do is write an HQL query that filters shipments `by user_id`. How can I do that? Thanks.

[image: The Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD)]

Comment: Post your entities. Without them, I could only assume how mappings look like and suggest something like `select s from Shipment s join s.parcels p join p.users u where u.id = :userId`.

Comment: Thank you, Stefan. Eventually, I found it in the hard way.